# Is there a way to replace cmd window with the new windows terminal?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, terminal-emulator

Now that we have the new Windows [Terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal), I never want to see the `cmd.exe` window again on my dev machine - is there any way I can make it replace it across the whole OS, just like in ConEmu and Cmder?

**Update:** I understand `cmd.exe` will never go away and I am not asking how to remove `cmd.exe` from Windows, what I would like to know is whether there is a way to redirect all input/output from `cmd.exe` to the Windows Terminal so that when I double-click a batch file or PowerShell script, it's output will open in a new tab within Windows Terminal (if I understand it right, this is also what ConEmu and Cmder do).

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1060

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes? I read all of this https://superuser.com/help/asking but still can't figure out what I might have done wrong.

Comment: Not sure,people should have left atleast a comment.

Comment: I think your question is also vague,cmd will never go.What do you meant by replace

Comment: "just like it is possible with ConEmu and Cmder?" - Since it has an executable just like ConEMu and Cmder, you should be able to, use that same process.  However, the new windows terminal isn't really ready for prime time.

Comment: Why not just use ConEmu and configure it so that any `cmd` window auto-opens within ConEmu?  Powershell would be the recommended shell to be used, as it provides vastly more ways to [customize](https://superuser.com/a/1543440/529800) the terminal appearance (`cmd` only programs can be executed in Powershell by prefacing the command with `cmd /c`)

Comment: ConEmu/Cmder is a usability nightmare and a general PITA. I would be more than happy to get rid of it once and for all, hence this question.

Comment: @bitbonk For whatever issues you have, have you referenced the extensive [man page](https://conemu.github.io/en/TableOfContents.html) documentation from ConEmu?  I've been using it for years without issue, so I can't help you there beyond offering the customized [`conemu.xml`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/ConEmu/ConEmu.xml) I use.  `clink` needs to be installed and it's path correctly set for `cmd` shell usage, however I never use an actual `cmd` shell, relying exclusively on PowerShell and executing `cmd`-only commands/programs by prefacing with `cmd /c`.

Comment: @bitbonk _Cont'd..."_ The `cmd` shell is so integrated into the core functionality of Windows, it's not likely to be replaced... while being archaic and lacking fundamental customization options, many CLI-only system applications can only be launched from within the `cmd` shell, whereas others may allow the application to be run from PowerShell, but will not recognize any parameters _(`dir` is a good example of this)_.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 11, you can choose the default terminal app to host the user interface for command-line applications.

1. Open the settings by pressing the `windows key` + `i`
2. Click on **Privacy & security**
3. Click on **For developers**
4. Scroll down until you see **Terminal**
5. From the dropdown now select **Windows Terminal** in favour of **Windows Console Host**

Even if you run a command like `cmd` in the future, it will bring up the Windows Terminal instead.

Perhaps this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`cmd.exe` doesn't have a window. `cmd.exe` is just a console application. The window you usually see when you start `cmd.exe` has nothing to do with `cmd.exe`, because it's a console window drawn by a part of Windows kernel called `conhost.exe`. You can replace `cmd.exe` with whatever you want, it still won't change the console window. The console window is automatically allocated by the kernel whenever the system starts any console process.

Your only option is to use `ConEmu`, which intercepts `conhost.exe` and automatically hides the allocated console.

Comment: This is no longer true... You can swap out conhost.exe for the new WindowsTerminal.exe in settings, see Ben's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is to replace conhost.exe, which is the host window for any console in windows systems.

To do this is really simple, just follow these instructions:

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1817

Answer (score 0):

Not without serious implications of applications that rely on the `cmd.exe` binary; WT is meant as a power tool for those of us that are very comfortable in the command interface and use it daily.

When it’s fully released, it will be a standard system binary though, just like PowerShell, and can be executed at will, integrated into all of the necessary system elements (e.g. Explorer, calling from search, etc.).  Currently, it’s still in pre-release and is a PTA to compile if you don’t know what you’re doing.

Answer (score -1):

With the following (run elevated), you can change how `.bat` files are started:

```bat
ftype batfile=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe "%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9"
```

- This does not change the working path, so it's not a full replacement - if you want to access files in the same folder, you need to change to the directory containing the batch file by adding this to your batch files:

  ```bat
  cd /d "%~dp0"
  ```

To revert:

```bat
ftype batfile="%1" %*
```

[image: Screenshot of wt.exe help]

Comment: `"%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9"` will fail if there are more than 9 parameters, or the parameters have spaces. Use `%*` instead

Comment: @phuclv with %* it did not work at all for me