# Make windows terminal default terminal for cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, windows-terminal

Want to have cmd.exe pop up in Window Terminal instead of its own window.

The fix outlined by Furty here ([Is there a way to replace cmd window with the new windows terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/1469293/is-there-a-way-to-replace-cmd-window-with-the-new-windows-terminal/1553266#1553266)) works for .bat files, but not for .bat files which have been converted to .exes. Those still launch in a normal cmd.exe window. Any fixes for this? Thanks!

Comment: How did you convert your bat files to exe? I'd would guess that is the key. The conversion either packages command.com with the bat, or has a direct call.

Comment: This program (https://bat-to-exe-converter-x64.en.softonic.com/). Is there a way I can check that?